# Table rendering twice in Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to Rails and programming in general, so am probably missing something fundamental here. I'm making a simple exercise tracker with 3 models: Exercise (table of different types of exercises), Workout (table of exercises done that session), Lift (join table between the two, and also includes the weight, sets and reps of each exercise done).

Problem: after adding more than 1 exercise to the workout, the table on the show view renders more than 1 entry for each exercise (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CG3A.jpg). Everything is being written correctly to the database.

Question: How can I make this render in the right way and what am I doing wrong?

Here is the **workouts controller**:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
end

def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @lift = Lift.new
end

def create
    @workout = Workout.new(params[:workout])
    @workout.save

    @lift = Lift.new(params[:lift])
    @lift.workout_id = @workout.id
    @lift.save

    redirect_to @workout
end

def show
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

end

def edit
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

    @lift = Lift.new(params[:lift])
    @lift.workout_id = @workout.id
    @lift.save

    redirect_to @workout

end

end
```

And here is the **Show view**

```
<h1> Workout Number <%= @workout.id %></h1>

<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>Excercize</th>
            <th>Sets</th>
            <th>Reps</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @workout.exercises.each do |w| %>
            <% @workout.lifts.each do |e| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= w.name %></td>
                <td><%= e.sets %></td>
                <td><%= e.reps %></td>
                <td><%= e.weight %></td> 
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </table>
    </div>

<div class="btn btn-primary">
    Add Exercise
    <%= link_to 'Add Exercise', edit_workout_path %>
</div>
```

**Edit** Adding the Workout model:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :id, :title, :body

  has_many :lifts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lifts

  has_many :exercises, through: :lifts

end
```

And the **Lifts model**

```
class Lift < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reps, :sets, :weight, :id,
:workout_id, :exercise_id, :exercise_name

  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout


end
```

**Exercise model**

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :primary_area, :secondary_area, 
  :id

  has_many :lifts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lifts

  has_many :workouts, through: :lifts

def name_for_select
    name.capitalize
end

end
```

Comment: Please show us your `app/models/workout.rb`

Comment: Just added above. Thanks

Comment: Can your explain relationship between `Lift` and `Exercise` model?

Comment: The Workout and Exercise models are a has many relationship through lifts. The exercise model has a list of different types of exercises (bench press, shoulder press, etc) and the Lift model also includes how much of each exercise was done during that particular workout (e.g., 2 sets, 10kg, 5reps).

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this should work. If not, please give me the error, and append code of another two models to question.

Comment: Got an error: "ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Workouts#show Association named 'lift' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it? " Also added the Exercise model so all three models are up there now

Comment: I think your data structure is flawed. Why don't you use a simpler approach? A workout has_many exercises which in turn has_many lifts? you could then use `<% @workout.exercises.each do |exercise| %>
<% exercise.lifts.each do |lift| %>

Comment: @BooVeMan your approach will lead to n+1 issue

Comment: @asiniy this can be mitigated by using Workout.references(:exercises => :lifts)

Answer (score 2):

Your exercise are twice because you iterate over your `@workout` model twice:

```
 <% @workout.exercises.each do |w| %>
   <% @workout.lifts.each do |e| %>
     <tr>
       <td><%= w.name %></td>
       <td><%= e.sets %></td>
       <td><%= e.reps %></td>
       <td><%= e.weight %></td> 
    </tr>
  </tbody> <!-- remove this tag out of the scope -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To get all working, you need something like that:

```
 <% @workout.exercises.inlcludes(:lifts).each do |exercise| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= exercise.name %></td>
     <td><%= exercise.lifts.first.sets %></td>
     <td><%= exercise.lifts.first.reps %></td>
     <td><%= exercise.lifts.first.weight %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Asiniy - are you missing a closed parentheses in the revised code? Can't figure it out

Comment: @workout.exercises.inlcludes(:lifts).each do |exercise|

Comment: Thanks guys- this is now working. Will have another think about the logic between the models again as something does seem a bit off- or at least not ideal

Comment: and this code will only show the first lift, if I understood correctly there can be several lifts in a workout for a specific exercise.

Comment: @BooVeMan exercise has just one lift related to workout.

Answer (score 1):

ya, your'e new, and i stopped reading your question after i saw your controller, so ill give you a little help writing better controllers.

```
def create
  workout = Workout.create params[:workout]
  workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
  redirect_to workout
end

def update
  workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
  workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
  redirect_to workout
end
```

dont make a **new** object and then **save** it - instead just call the `create` method straight on it.
while workout ist having many lifts, there is automatically the correct association for the lift, so no need to set it manually.

sorry for highjacking, just want to let you know how to write better controllers :-)

**edit**

or just go DRY

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @lift = Lift.new
  end

  def create
    workout = Workout.create params[:workout]
    workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
    redirect_to workout
  end

  def show
    @workout = current_workout
  end

  def edit
    @workout = current_workout
  end

  def update
    current_workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
    redirect_to current_workout
  end

  private
  def  current_workout
    Workout.find params[:id]
  end

end
```

**edit2: or go totally short**

no need to write `def show` if nothing happens inside. before_filter is loading the @workout and the template will be rendered. rails is cool!

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load_workout, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  def index
    @workouts = Workout.all
  end

  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
    @lift = Lift.new
  end

  def create
    workout = Workout.create params[:workout]
    workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
    redirect_to workout
  end

  def update
    @workout.lifts.create params[:lift]
    redirect_to @workout
  end

  private
  def  load_workout
    @workout = Workout.find params[:id]
  end

end
```

btw: dont just copy this controller, i'm pretty sure your whole workout/lifts logic is off.